# Band structure diagrams

Tags: quantum-mechanics, condensed-matter, measurements, electronic-band-theory

In band structure diagrams, usually we show the dispersion relation between energy $E$ and the wave vector $\textbf{k}$.

Consider the band structure of $\alpha$-Polonium. Shown in the graph below.
[image]

Note that the values $\Gamma, X, M, R$ represent different positions of the wave vector $\textbf{k}$ in reciprocal space, $E_f$ denotes the Fermi energy.
There are three different lines depending on the orbitals, lower is $6s$ and the upper ones are $6px, 6py, 6pz$.

Now I quite understand the mathematics behind this but my questions are:

What can we say about real $\alpha$-polonium sample from the graph?

If I would like to measure the band structure, what kind of experiment would I have to preform? Would I have to, for example, isolate one atom of the sample, then measure it's energy in one state - then excite/ de-excite it to another one and measure again?

The image was taken from this [video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=6wwkdFLBmBw).

Comment: Well, you can say that it is a metal. There are various experiments to measure band structure which various solid state physics books at least allude to.